# Populate part of an HTML form with data from php database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I want to create a html form that connects to a table I have in a database in phpmyadmin. I have 3 columns: Name, Decision, Time - along with a submit button. I want to pull the name from the phpmyadmin table and populate it in the form and have them select the decision from a drop down menu, and the time auto update to the time it is when they hit submit. I can figure out how to have a drop down menu, but not prepopulate the name field or auto update the time field. If you can help with any part of this that would be great. I have attached the script I currently have here:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Linker Tracker</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
      <?php
      include "db.inc.php";//database connection
      $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Tester");
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))?>
        <form action="edit_data.php" method="post">
        <td><tr><input type="text" value="$row[Name]"></tr></td>
        <td><tr><select name="pulldown" name="Decision"/>
        <option value=" ">Unworked</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
           <option value="No">No</option> 
        <option value="Maybe">Maybe</option?>
          </tr></td>
        <td><tr><input type="text" name="$row[Time]"></tr></td>
        <input type="submit" name=<a href=\"edit_data.php"></a>
      </form>
      </table></body></html>
```

Comment: that's not going to work. your `$row[...]` vars aren't variables - they're just plain text, since they're not inside `<?php ... ?>` code blocks. and same for `\"edit`... it's not in php mode, so `\"` is just plain text, and means absolutely NOTHING to your browser. and `name=<a` is just plain broken html

Comment: I dont understand `name=<a href=\"edit_data.php"`.. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Scrap everything in the while() code.  It isn't valid PHP anyway.  Replace it with var_dump($row).  Are you actually getting results from MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your table as

```
      <table border="1">
      <?php
      include "db.inc.php";//database connection which returns $dbLink as the connection.
      $result = mysqli_query($dbLink, "SELECT * FROM Tester");
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))?>
        <form action="edit_data.php" method="post">
        <td><tr><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Name']; ?>"></tr></td>
        <td><tr><select name="pulldown" name="Decision"/>
        <option value=" ">Unworked</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
           <option value="No">No</option> 
        <option value="Maybe">Maybe</option?>
          </tr></td>
        <td><tr><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Time']; ?>"></tr></td>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"></a>
      </form>
      </table>
```

Specifying the value just like `value="$row[Name]"` wont tell the compiler that it is a php code. It just treats as normal HTML.

Thus you have to specify the value inside php code blocks (`<?php... ?>`);

Comment: When I rewrite it like that, I get nothing in the Name or Time columns. But if I do an echo to see the data in the table the Name and the Time columns are populated. Thoughts?

Comment: That shouldnt happen...Name or Time columns..which columns? are you reffering to the input fields?

Comment: <td><tr><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row[Name]; ?>"></tr></td> shows up as an empty text box and so does  <td><tr><input type="text" name="<?php echo $row[Time]; ?>"></tr></td>

Comment: It should be `<?php echo $row['Name']; ?>`..did it work if you give that inside a `<tr>`?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer, your answer is correct but you had omitted the MySQLi database object variable. The code will now work as expected as long as the db include file is written correctly. Perhaps if you're feeling extra helpful to the OP you can edit and include that too? Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the edit.. @Martin Valuable  piece of work..:)

Comment: @Julie you need to review the code in Lal's answer, and also update your db.inc.php file so that `$dbLink = mysqli_connect(...);` Look on PHP manual for http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Here is my db.inc.php.
Even with the changes Martin made and changing it to $connection instead of $dblink it still just is a blank text box.
<?php define("DB_SERVER", "localhost"); define("DB_USER", "root");
                define("DB_PASS", "MYPASSWORD");
                define("DB_NAME", "Linker_Tracker");
  // 1. Create a database connection
  $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  // Test if connection succeeded
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {die("Database connection failed: " .
         mysqli_connect_error() ." (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")");}?>